# Heroku and Django, database resets when heroku restarts the site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, heroku, hosting

After 30mins of not being used Heroju resets my django site, however when the site is reset the database/models controlled and changed in the admin page are reset back to when the site was first uploaded. How do i stop this and make changes made in admin mode permanently to the site?

thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using sqlite as the database. You must not use that on Heroku, as it is stored on the ephemeral file system. Use the proper Postgres add-on.